# Confusion over Matrix rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to make a function in C++ that accepts an angle 'a', and a vector 'v' as arguments and returns a matrix. 'a' should represent the amount that is rotated around vector 'v', an arbitrary axis, and the matrix returned should contain values that will make the rotation  around v by certain degrees, possible.

However, I have no idea how matrices should end up looking, or if I do, how and why the values are assigned.

Here's an example.

values that are passed in..

```
a = 120, v = vector(1,1,1)
```

Magic happens

matrix data returned..

```
{ 0, 0, 1, 0
  1, 0, 0, 0
  0, 1, 0, 0
  0, 0, 0, 1
}
```

So the issue is, why are the 1's and 0's placed in such ways? What is the relationship between that specific matrix and a matrix that contains cosines, sins, -sins, or 1-cos? As far as I know, they're all rotation matrices

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What do you mean rotated around vector 'v?' Do you mean rotate the vector through an angle about the origin? In that case you do not even need a vector as an input to construct the rotation matrix.

Comment: Rotation is somewhat ill defined.  You need to rotate about _what_?  In 2 dimensions this generally means the $z$-axis (an imaginary pole perpendicular to the origin).  As soon as you go to higher dimensions there is more than one pole to rotate about.  You can see that in $3$ dimensions there are several [ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations) of rotating.

Answer (score 1):

See *Quaternion-derived rotation matrix* [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation)

$a=(a_x,a_y,a_z)$ is the axis, $c=\cos \theta$, $s=\sin \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle of rotation.